# I want to store spinner value in String and display it on a Textview using onItemselectedListener

Tags: android

my code is not working and I am not getting the value on textview ,suppose my spinner pops up and I select other value than at the same time my textview value should change with the string value of spinner item slected

```
    package com.vedicrishiastro.kundli.Screens.Extras;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.vedicrishiastro.kundli.R;
import com.vedicrishiastro.kundli.Screens.AbstractActivity;

public class Settings extends AbstractActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private LinearLayout linearSelectLang,linearSetDefault,linearSelectPanch;
    private TextView txtSelectLang,txtSetDefault,txtSelectPanch;
    private Spinner spinner1,spinner2,spinner3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        linearSelectLang = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearSelectLang);
        linearSetDefault = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearSetDefault);
        linearSelectPanch = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearSelectPanch);

        spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.settingSpinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.settingSpinner2);
        spinner3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.settingSpinner3);

        txtSelectLang = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selectLangtext);
        txtSetDefault = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.setdefaulttext);
        txtSelectPanch = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selectPanchtext);

        linearSelectLang.setOnClickListener(this);
        linearSetDefault.setOnClickListener(this);
        linearSelectPanch.setOnClickListener(this);
        spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinner3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        int id = view.getId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.LinearSelectLang:
            {
                spinner1.performClick();
                spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (position == 0) {
                            txtSelectLang.setText("English");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            txtSelectLang.setText("हिंदी");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

                spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
            case R.id.LinearSetDefault:
            {
                spinner2.performClick();
                String text = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                txtSetDefault.setText(text);
                spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
            case R.id.LinearSelectPanch:
            {
                spinner3.performClick();
                String text = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                txtSelectPanch.setText(text);
                spinner3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't add the Listener inside a click method...

Comment: @RobinVinzenz than ?

Comment: add your OnItemSelectedListener in a lifecycle method e.g. onCreate. Rethink your code and try to understand what your code does right now

Comment: Figure it out yourself, i've given you enough hints, you can do it,

Comment: @you guys just want to play voting games ? right ?

Comment: Robin is right, You should set Your onItemSelectedListener outside the clickListener. The clickListener may consume the onItemSelected event. And what You mean by "voting games"? Do You mean, if You are voting me down, I will do this too on Your questions? Well, I think it´s a shame here on SO that poeple voting down without an explanation, but doing the same just because of a revenge is also a shame.

Answer (score 0):

In You case, You should first set the `onItemSelectedListener` outside the `onClick`, for a better syntax. But this is not the case for not firing. The case is, that You set `performClick()` **BEFORE** You set the `spinner` to `ItemSelectedListener()`. You have to **FIRST** set `onItemSelectedListener` and then call `performClick()`

and For Your `spinner2` and `spinner3` , You haven´t set any `onItemSelectedListener()`.

### EDIT

For clearance, set performClick **AFTER** `onItemSelectedListener()`:

```
 case R.id.LinearSelectLang:
            {

                spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (position == 0) {
                            txtSelectLang.setText("English");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            txtSelectLang.setText("हिंदी");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

                spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            spinner1.performClick() //here set performClick
            break;
```

But really....set `onItemSelectedListener` **OUTSIDE** the onClick of Your `Button`.

Comment: but when i try to put performclick inside onitemselectedlistener it gives me error

Comment: You cannot put this inside onItemSelected...You have to put it AFTER onItemSelectedListener()...